# Eclipse (Neon) & EGit: how to (re-)apply stashed changes? Where is the functionality hiding?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) and before I switched to another branch I have stashed some changes I had been working on. 
My initial intention was to re-apply these changes to the other branch,  something that - according to the Git help - should be possible.
But then I was unable to find any stashing-related functionality anywhere. How/where is that hidden?
I thus switched back to the branch from where I had stashed my changes. But here again: I can't find any menu-entry or button or whatever to re-apply my staged changes! Where have these changes gone to? How to I restore the branch to the stashed state?

I have searched SO and there are a few entries mentioning that stashing and stashed changes are accessible via the Team-menu, but not so. There is no such entry in the Team menu!

Comment: How did you stash changes in the first place if it's not in the UI?

Comment: Stashing of uncommitted changes to the current branch is offered, if one selects to check out a different branch. So, there, one can select it. In the meantime I found that unstashing (or re-applying) those stashed changes is offered in the Package Explorer view (not - as one would expect - in any of the Git-related views). I tried that twice by now, but both attempts failed. So - in essence: my saved/stashed changes were lost. :-( 
I'll report again with the precise error msg. once I try that again.

Answer (score 11):

Open Git Perspective -> Git Repositories View -> Expand your repository -> Stashed Commits -> select your stash -> right click and Apply Stashed Changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least in my version of Eclipse (Oxygen), right-clicking on the repository entry in the repositories view finds the "Stashes" menu, with an option to stash the current changes, or to select a particular stash entry.  Once you select and view the stash entry, you can apply it to your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git pop` to pop your stashed changes from the stash, or `git stash apply` to apply the changes while leaving them on the stash stack.

Comment: Am I correct if I deduct from that response that there is no way to trigger these same steps via the Egit GUI?

Comment: Tbh I don't know, I don't use Eclipse.